# How could I change the the timer to refresh after every hour instead of every 24?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to make the timer run for an hour then refresh back to an hour, instead of it being reset every 24 hours, I've been struggling to find the solution to do so without the timer breaking, so if I could get help understanding why it's not functioning the way I'd want it to :(

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){


    /**
     * Initialize JAVASCRIPT Plugins
     */

    // TIMER ================================================================================
    // Initialize a single instance of a timer.
    var initTimer = function(timer){
        var timerElem = jQuery(timer);

        var timerExpires = localStorage.getItem('timerExpires');       //Sets item in local storage

        var expiresIn   = timerElem.attr('data-expires-in');
        var hrName    = timerElem.attr('data-hours');
        var minName   = timerElem.attr('data-minutes');
        var secName   = timerElem.attr('data-seconds');

        var returnedExpirationDate = new Date();

        function createNewDate() {
            var expirationDate = new Date();
            if (expiresIn === "") {
                //Set defaultDate to tomorrow
                expirationDate.setHours(24,00,00,00);         // Set time to tomorrow (in milliseconds)
                expirationDate = new Date(expirationDate);    // Converts milliseconds to date format
            } else {

                //Set defaultDate to new Date().getTime() + 3600000 * expiresIn
                expiresIn = Number(expiresIn);                                  // Converts expiresIn string to a number
                expirationDate = expirationDate.getTime() + (3600000 * expiresIn);               // Adds expiresIn to the original time the page was accessed (in milliseconds)
                expirationDate = new Date(expirationDate);                      // Converts milliseconds to date format

            }

           localStorage.setItem('timerExpires', expirationDate);
           return expirationDate;
        }

        if (timerExpires === null) {
            //[IF] expiresIn
            returnedExpirationDate = createNewDate();
        } else {

            var expDate = Date.parse(timerExpires);
            var newDate = new Date().getTime();
            //if time has expired, reset date
            if (expDate - newDate <= 0) {
                //Reset date
                returnedExpirationDate = createNewDate();
            }else{
                returnedExpirationDate = new Date(timerExpires);
            }
        }

        // COUNTDOWN TIMER
        timerElem.countdown({
            date: returnedExpirationDate,
            render: function(data) {

                jQuery(this.el).html(
                    "<div class='cntdown-time'>"+this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2)+
                    ":"+this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2)+
                    ":"+this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2)+
                    "</div><table class='cntdown-desc'><tr><td>"+hrName+"</td><td>"+minName+"</td><td>"+secName+"</td></tr></table>"
                );
            }
        });
    };

    // Grab all timers on the page and initialize
    var timers = jQuery('.countdown');  
    jQuery.each( timers, function(index, timer){
        initTimer(timer);       
    });


    // DATE =================================================================================

    var initDate = function(dateElem){
        var dateObj = jQuery(dateElem);

        var date = new Date();                                                        // Get the current date
        var months = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];       // Give months proper number
        var month   = months[date.getMonth()];                                                       // Get Month
        var day     = date.getDate();                                                                // Get Day

        if(day < 10){                                                                                // IF the date is less than 10 (before the 10th of the month)
            day = "0" + day;                                                                         // Add a zero in before the number
        }else{                                                                                       // ELSE
            day = day;                                                                               // Keep original date, do not add zero
        }

        var year    = date.getFullYear();                                                            // Get Year

        console.log(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
        var customDate = dateObj.attr('data-custom-date');                                           // Custom date attribute


        if (customDate === "") {
            var output = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

            jQuery(dateElem).html(output);
        } else {

            jQuery(dateElem).html(customDate);
        }
    }

    var dateWrapper = jQuery('.date_wrapper');                                                       // Getting all date containers
    jQuery.each(dateWrapper, function(index, dateElem){
        initDate(dateElem);                                                                                  // Initiate the Date function
    });

});
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? It looks to me like you can just change the hours from `24` to `1`.

Comment: why only the javascript tag, that's mean you want an answer without jQuery ?

Comment: @MisterJojo , Yes, I'm just trying to figure out how to get 1 hour instead of 24 with the the cycling one hour reset

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems very complex. I would suggest you create a class `Timer` and use dependency injection to pass in e.g. the HTML element it should be attached to and other parameters you might want to set as for example the `resetAfterMs` parameter which determines after however many milliseconds your timer should refresh. This approach will enable you to create however many timers you want just by creating more instances of your `Timer` class.

In terms of how to display the timer you could also use the `toLocaleTimeString()` with some format options. It is important that you use `Etc/UTC` or another timezone with no offset from UTC (see [Wiki - List of timzones in tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)) in order to get the desired output, otherwise that offset will be added to the time and it could be e.g. `01:00:03` (GMT+1) instead of `00:00:03` (GMT+0 = UTC).

This solution uses [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval), but you could also use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout?retiredLocale=de) with some small adjustments to the solution. Be aware that both do not guarantee that the callbacks will be executed exactly after the specified time but they will be scheduled after that time and may be executed at the specified time or later.

> This solution is one of many possible solutions and has some drawbacks but I wanted to add another approach in contrast to the way you are approaching it as I find this solution to be a lot cleaner and readable. But you can pick and choose, combine or come up with another possible solution yourself.

```js
class Timer {
  constructor(htmlElement, resetAfterMs) {
    this.htmlElement = htmlElement;
    this.resetAfterMs = resetAfterMs;
    this.resetAt = undefined;
  }

  start() {
    this.startedAt = new Date();
    this.resetAt = new Date(this.startedAt.getUTCMilliseconds() + this.resetAfterMs);
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.updateTimer(), 1000);
  }

  reset() {
    this.stop();
    this.start();
  }

  continue () {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.updateTimer(), 1000);
  }

  updateTimer() {
    const duration = new Date() - this.startedAt;
    if (duration >= this.resetAfterMs) this.reset();
    const formatOpts = {
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
      second: "2-digit",
      // IANA timezone name for UTC! otherwise locale string will add offsets as appropriate for your timezone
      timeZone: "Etc/UTC"
    };
    this.htmlElement.textContent = new Date(duration).toLocaleTimeString("de-DE", formatOpts);
  }

  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const [timer1div, timer2div] = [...document.querySelectorAll(".timer")];
  const fiveSeconds = 5 * 1000;
  const tenSeconds = 10 * 1000;
  // create timer and provide a HTML element it should be attached to
  const timer1 = new Timer(timer1div, fiveSeconds);
  const timer2 = new Timer(timer2div, tenSeconds);
  timer1.start();
  timer2.start();
})
```

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 10px;
}

.timer{
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<span>Timer 1 (resets after 5s):</span>
<div class="timer"></div>
<span>Timer 2 (resets after 10s):</span>
<div class="timer"></div>
```

> You could extend on above implementation and e.g. also show milliseconds and provide an additional parameter `refreshAfterMs` to determine when your timer should re-render and then you would be able to have a more granular timer.